# How to prevent wrapping on a space character?

Tags: white-space

I am creating a list of special characters used for delimitation in my work.

```
"-","_"," " are delimiters
```

But the latex code is wrapping on `" "`

```
"-","_","
" are delimiters
```

How do I treat `" "` as a word that shouldn't be wrapped?

Comment: Use a tie `~`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tie `~` can be used as per [Werner's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) comment.

```
"-","_","~" are delimiters
```